# Lately vs. Recently lesson plan

Tags: word-choice, grammar, morphology, lexicon

I am currently taking linguistics and am required to tutor a student based on errors within a writing sample she has provided me. Currently, I am developing activities for determining when to use recently vs. lately but upon writing sentences myself I realize as a native speaker I can choose what sounds better to me but i can't put into words why one is the better choice. Any advice?

Comment: What makes you believe there is anything more than a stylistic difference? This seems to be nothing more than personal preference.

Comment: my student wrote "one study I read lately states that..." the clear word choice here would be "one study I read recently states that..." just trying to come up with he words that explain the word choice error.

Answer (score 1):

Lately is used to describe a repetitive event in the past which hasn't occurred in near past.

> I haven't played cricked lately.

Recently is used to denote occurrence of an event in the near past.

> I went to the workshop recently.

For more elaborate answer, please refer [Difference between "recently" and "lately"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32571/difference-between-recently-and-lately)